# Issue in rJava integration using JRI

Tags: java, r

I am beginners in java with R integration, I have same problem,
[Problems with JRI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790505/problems-with-jri/34663483?noredirect=1#comment57073998_34663483)

but this code is working in my case,

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;

public class HelloRWorld {
   Rengine rengine; // initialized in constructor or autowired

   public void helloRWorld() {
      rengine.eval(String.format("greeting <- '%s'", "Hello R World"));
      REXP result = rengine.eval("greeting");
      System.out.println("Greeting from R: "+result.asString());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Greeting from R: Hello R World
```

When I try second code I got an error

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;

public class TestR {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x1 = 10,x2 =30;
    Rengine r = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"}, false, null);r.eval(String.format("greeting <- '%s'", "Hello R World"));

    r.eval(String.format("newDataddata.frame(x1=%s,x2=%s)", x1, x2));
    REXP result = r.eval("predict(modelData)");
    System.out.println(result.asDouble());
    }

}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestR.main(TestR.java:11)
```

Comment: The R code makes no sense and is invalid, so you're likely getting errors which is why the `result` is `NULL`. Try with valid R code and make sure what you're evaluating is actually a numeric vector when you use `asDouble()` on it.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, can you please share some guide or tutorial on java programming for R?